# Determine the point of intersection between a line and contour represented by list of points

Tags: c++, opencv, line, contour

Given : List of points representing a closed contour 
Task  : Choose a random point on the contour and shoot a ray inside the contour and determine the point where the ray intersects the contour. This needs to be implemented with some programming language.

The approach I have in mind is to interpolate the points and solve the equations of the line and the curve. Is there any library in C++ which can achieve this or any simpler math besides interpolation, or any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would treat the contour as a set of line segments and perform an intersection test between each line segment and your ray. [Geometric tools](http://www.geometrictools.com/Source/Intersection2D.html#LinearLinear) has a very comprehensive library of intersections tests and I've used it successfully for many applications.

Comment: Thank your for you insight. I used your idea and got implementation idea from https://rootllama.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/ray-line-segment-intersection-test-in-2d/